# php -v showing 5.4 and phpinfo show 5.6

Tags: 12.04, php, xampp

I am trying to install `laravel` that need `> 5.5php` version. My current php is of `version 5.6`, but composer detect `version 5.4` and gives error.

How to remove `php 5.4` or make the correct version for `php -v`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged that you're using XAMPP, which doesn't actually install PHP to your system. The version *inside* XAMPP may be php 5.6, but the version installed to your system is different.

Since you're on 12.04, I don't think you can install php 5.6 from the standard repos using apt-get.

You have two options:

1) Install php 5.6 manually. This is the best way, but it may be difficult for a first timer. You will also need to install apache 2.4, as PHP 5.6 is not compatible with the version in 12.04 (I think):
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

2) Install PHP 5.6 from a 3rd party repository. This is risky, as you are adding an unverified (but popular) repository to your apt sources. It will also be the most simple way, though: https://joshtronic.com/2014/09/14/upgrade-php-53-to-php-56-on-ubuntu-1204-lts/

Comment: i will try and get back to u